# Controlled serialization in .NET

Tags: .net, serialization

for some reasons I need to control the process of object serialization in .NET. I have to control that properties should be serialized. This process should be dynamical so, at one request one set of properties should be serialized and at the other one - another. I'm curious is it possible to implement by the already existed mechanism or I have to design some custom serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ISerializable` interface allows you to do exactly that. Basically, you control which values are added to the "property bag" (`SerializationInfo`) when the serialization is being performed. Notice that you're not even limited to properties of the type, as shown below.

```
public class StackOverflow_10639264
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyType : ISerializable
    {
        public string SerializedAM { get; set; }
        public string SerializedPM { get; set; }
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            if (now.Hour < 12)
            {
                info.AddValue("MyValue", this.SerializedAM);
            }
            else
            {
                info.AddValue("MyValue", this.SerializedPM);
                info.AddValue("NotAProperty", "Hello");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyType));
        dcs.WriteObject(ms, new MyType { SerializedAM = "AM", SerializedPM = "PM" });
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! Looks like it's exactly what I need!

Comment: one more question... how to pass my own parameters inside GetObjectData? What is the good practice? I need to pass there some object that will describe what properties should be serialized...

Comment: GetObjectData is an instance method, so it has access to all the members of the type which contains it (in the example above, `MyType`). If you want to define what should be serialized, you can store it in some field / property in the type itself.

Comment: I thought about it... but if I want to serialize array of values (let's say 1000) I have to pass this configuration parameter to 1000 different objects... don't like it. Now thinking about implementation some interface that will take that config parameter from some store.

Comment: Hmm... but how it would work if class marked with [DataContract] instead of [Serializable] attribute?